# How to WDDX ColdFusion struct and maintain pointers or recursion

Tags: pointers, struct, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, wddx

I am using WDDX to to store a ColdFusion struct in a database, and I would like to maintain the pointers.  Here's an example (sorry, the shorthand notation may be full of errors b/c I hardly ever use it):

```
tshirt={color={selected="red",options=["red","blue","yellow","white"]}};
tshirt.front= {colors=tshirt.color,design="triangle",ink="green"};
tshirt.back= {color=tshirt.color,design="square",ink="black"};
```

Right now, *tshirt.front.color*, *tshirt.back.color* and *tshirt.color* are all pointers to the same struct.  If I change *tshirt.color.selected* to "blue", *tshirt.back.color.selected* and *tshirt.front.color.selected* will also be "blue".

However, suppose I WDDX *tshirt* and then unWDDX it. When I change *tshirt.color.selected* to "white", it is not changed in *tshirt.front.color.selected* or *tshirt.back.color.selected*.

**Can anyone suggest another way to serialize and unserialize data that would preserve the pointers?**

Just a few links that I've been using to research so far:

- http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/01/random-unsuccessful-experiment.html
- http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/the-inner-workings-of-a-coldfusion-array-and-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ObjectSave()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ObjectSave), new in CF9:

> **Description**
>
> Converts a ColdFusion array, CFC, DateTime object, Java object, query,
>   or structure into a serializable binary object and optionally saves
>   the object in a file.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A serializable binary representation of the object.

```
<cfscript>
    shirtdata = objectSave(tshirt);
    tshirt2 = objectLoad(shirtdata);

    tshirt2.color.selected = "blue";
    writeOutput(tshirt2.front.colors.selected);  // "blue" => reference kept
</cfscript>
```

Live Demo: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=L0g211aD

Comment: I am curious how it behaves with regard to backward compatibility. Sounds like it is based on the java model, which uses serialVersionUID. If you change versions, and the uid value for a the serialized class changes, you won't be able to deserialize the object in the new version. Hopefully CF took that into consideration.

Comment: I did a test from cf9 to cf10 and from cf10 to cf9 and they both worked correctly.

Comment: @jessieloo - Just saw your comment. Are you using the same jvm version for CF9 and 10?

Comment: @Leigh, they are not the same jvm version.  CF10 is 1.7.0_51_b13, CF9 is 1.6.0_17_b04